# Am I doing something wrong when I shuffle guild cards into the Age 3 cards

Tags: 7-wonders-duel

In 7 Wonders Duel, the instructions say when you are preparing the Age 3 deck you should remove 3 cards from the deck and add 3 random guild cards. I assume the guild cards should be shuffled in so I usually just put the 3 cards in random positions and shuffle the deck. However, the guild cards have different colored backs (they are purple like the Age 3 cards but are darker) so I can clearly see where the guild cards are and know where they are going to be when I build the oval-shaped layout. This seems wrong to me. Should I close my eyes when I shuffle the deck or is there a reason why they stand out? Should they go in a certain position when the cards are placed?

Comment: You might know they're guild cards, but you won't know *which* guilds they are.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb yea but it's easy to memorize what those cards are, and one of them might be exactly what a player needs and there is a 1/3 chance of getting it. If that player is shuffling and their turn is next, they might, subconsciously or not so subconsciously, arrange the cards so that they get a guild card next.

Comment: It's only a 1/3 chance if you looked at the guild cards you put away and thereby know which 3 were added. *Technically* I don't think the rules strictly say that you can't look at the ones that don't get added... but it doesn't seem to be in the spirit of the game to look at them. After all, you aren't allowed to look at the removed age cards. Until a guild card is flipped up, you should never have a way of knowing which of the 7 guilds it is.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb ah yea I forgot that there was a pool of 7 guild cards. Haven't played in a while.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong.

Looking at rules [here](http://www.7wondersduel.com/files/rules/7-Wonders-Duel-Rules-US.pdf) it says :-

> Return to the box, without looking at them, 3 cards from each Age deck.
>   Then randomly draw 3 Guild cards and add them to the Age III deck without
>   looking at them. Return the remaining Guilds to the box.

My other reference for this is playing the 7 Wonders Duel app.  I can confirm that also places the guilds in random positions and the face down ones have a visible darker back.

As for the reasons you would have to ask the designer for the certain answer.  However as a player its very useful to know if a face down card is a guild.  Lets say your opponent is close to achieving military or scientific supremacy?  if you are going to be forced to reveal a card on your turn wouldn't be better to reveal a card that you know cant give them an automatic win?

Like wise if you as a player are close to winning with military or scientific supremacy, would it be better to build a wonder granting those all important extra turns in the hope you reveal the exact card you need and knowing its not a guild increases that chance.